# Formatting json data using jq

Tags: json, unix, jq

I am trying to convert the json from the following format to a different format but I am getting am unable to generate the required format format:

**Input Json:**

```
[  
   {  
      "name":"Successful retrieval",
      "elements":[  
         {  
            "scenario":"First",
            "steps":[  
               {  
                  "name":"as a customer",
                  "result":{  
                     "status":"passed",
                     "duration":29428
                  }
               },
               {  
                  "name":"I hit API",
                  "result":{  
                     "status":"passed",
                     "duration":210403731
                  }
               },
               {  
                  "name":"API should respond",
                  "result":{  
                     "status":"passed",
                     "duration":1246183
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

**Desired Format:**

```
    {  
   "name":"Successful retrieval",
   "Result":[  
      {  
         "stepName":"as a customer",
         "status":"passed"
      },
      {  
         "stepName":"I hit API",
         "status":"passed"
      },
      {  
         "stepName":"API should respond",
         "status":"passed"
      }
   ]
}
```

**JQ command used:**

```
  jq ['.[] | { name: .name, steps: .elements[].steps[]} | 
{name:.name, stepName:.steps.name, status:.steps.result.status}']
```

With the above command, I am getting the following format:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Successful retrieval",
    "stepName": "as an  Synapse API customer",
    "status": "passed"
  },
  {
    "name": "Successful retrieval",
    "stepName": "I hit API",
    "status": "passed"
  },
  {
    "name": "Successful retrieval",
    "stepName": "API should respond",
    "status": "passed"
  }
]
```

I tried using the `join`but it didn't work. Any pointers will be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
  .[]
| .Result = [
      .elements[]
    | .steps[]
    | {stepName:.name, status:.result.status}
  ]
| del(.elements)
```

Here is a sample run assuming your data is in `input.json`:

```
$ jq '.[] | .Result = [.elements[] | .steps[] | {stepName:.name, status:.result.status}] | del(.elements)' input.json
{
  "name": "Successful retrieval",
  "Result": [
    {
      "stepName": "as a customer",
      "status": "passed"
    },
    {
      "stepName": "I hit API",
      "status": "passed"
    },
    {
      "stepName": "API should respond",
      "status": "passed"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a minor variation on jq170727's answer.

The last step builds the object out of the parts you want rather than deleting the ones you don't want.

```
jq '.[]
| .Result =
  [  
     .elements[]
     | .steps[]
     | { stepName:.name, status:.result.status }
  ]
| { name, Result }'
```